# Blocking a call using react-native

Tags: react-native

I am new to react-native. I am trying to make an application where I can block incoming calls. Is there any npm-library that can help me achieve it.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: @Mumbaikaroo7 did you got any solution for this

Comment: No I didn't ...

Comment: @Mumbaikar007 Did you find anything for this?

Comment: No luck! I had to shift back to Android...

Comment: have you find any code or library.